# Python timeout error when trying to scrape sizes on product page

Tags: python

hi can anyone get this to work - I am trying to scrape sizes from an interactive dropdown selector but keep getting a timeout error

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.asos.com/nike/nike-air max-95-logo-leather-trainers-in-dark-navy-orange/prd/20750072 colourwayid=60085113", timeout=60.0).content)


print([size.text.strip() for size in soup.find(class_="colour-size select")])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It's because you've forgot the parameter `headers`
- Try again:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.asos.com/nike/nike-air max-95-logo-leather-trainers-in-dark-navy-orange/prd/20750072 colourwayid=60085113", 
timeout=60.0, 
headers=headers).content)
```

Comment: thank you! looks like what I'm scraping is giving me a type error. might be because its an interactive selector

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
>>>